# Targeting one specific value based off index

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, json

I'm using jQuery to populate a standard HTML select list from a JSON file. The populate function works fine, but now I need to target a specific value of whatever dropdown is selected to get a value. The .0xx AFM is what goes in the dropdown box, the value is the value that's assigned to the select element, and the price is the price associated with that dropdown. What I'm trying to achieve is use jQuery or JS to get the price associated with the selected dropdown. That way I can use the price value as a variable in a calculation formula.

[image: My JSON file]
[image: Populate JSON code]
[image: Drop down]

Comment: I think you may need to provide a bit of your code for context-- I'm not completely clear on what it is you need to achieve here...

Comment: Please, you're not the first time here on StackOverflow, I'm sure you have seen people posting code inside Code Snippets. [edit], and create a [mcve]

Comment: I'm looking to create a function that gets the price of the selected dropdown from the JSON. So when the first value is select (as seen in the photo) the function will result in a price of 1 per the JSON file. The second dropdown option produces as price of "2'. I was trying to index it based off of the value from the dropdown but I wasn't sure how to target the price part of it. @AlexanderNied

Comment: What do you want to DO with the price? Just `console.log` it when the select the item from the list... or?

Comment: It's going to be a var for another function that I have to write still. I haven't done anything with it yet because I wasn't sure how to get the price. @Chase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the price each time a value is selected from the list. I can't edit your code because it is a screenshot, but this would go INSIDE the get getJSON call but AFTER the each loop.

Something like:

```js
// inside your getJson call, after your $.each loop

$(dropdown).on('change', function() {
  const selectedValue = $(this).val();
  const match = Object.values(data).find(entry => entry.value === selectedValue);
  console.log(match && match.price);
});
```

Comment: `this.value` and save 4 bytes ;)

Comment: It works, but when I look in the console it prints it 3x?

Comment: Sounds like 1) You put it INSIDE the each loop (don't do that) or 2) Your are fetching your JSON 3 times and binding 3 event handlers that do the same thing.

Comment: Works like a charm, I appreciate it! Just tried my hand at jQuery today...